# how to make mobile app dsign reponsive in ionic with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have ionic app which is built with ionic . Design of that page is designed with css  but the problem is design is not responsive for every mobile device. How i can make id responsive for evey mobile device?

```
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" id="start" class="background">
      <div id="product_background">
        <Topbar />
        <div class="container">
          <ion-text color class="top-left">
            <h1>ARTICS PRO</h1>
          </ion-text>
           <ion-text color class="heart_icon">
            <ion-icon :icon="heartOutline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon :icon="shareSocial"></ion-icon>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text color class="top-left2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text color class="bottom-right">
            <p>ARTICS 7</p>
          </ion-text>


          <ion-text color class="bottom-right2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>


          <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:100vw" />
        </div>
        <div slot="bottom" id="product_price">
        <h2>$3,9000</h2>
      </div>

      </div>
      <div id="product_info">
        <p>Product Information</p>
      </div>
      <div id="cart_icon">
         <ion-icon :icon="cart"></ion-icon>
      </div>


    </ion-content>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonContent, IonPage, IonText,IonIcon } from "@ionic/vue";
import Topbar from "../Resources/Topbar.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { heartOutline,shareSocial,cart } from 'ionicons/icons';
export default {
  name: "Index",
  components: { IonContent, IonPage, Topbar, IonText,IonIcon },
  setup() {
    return {
      router: useRouter(),
      heartOutline,shareSocial,cart
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
ion-content.background {
  --background:  url("../../assets/product_background.png") 0 0/100% 93% no-repeat;
}
#product_background {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px;
}
#product_price {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: 16px;
}
.bottom-right2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}
#product_info{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 16px;
}
#cart_icon {
  position: absolute;
 bottom: 70px;
  right: 50px;
}
#product_price{
    position: absolute;
 bottom: 150px;
  left: 20px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.heart_icon{
   position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 6px;
}
</style>
```

May be because of i used html element instead of ionic component but what that be the replacement of html tags in ionic

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is providing a grid to make your html responsive. You'll need to use ion-grid, ion-row and ion-col.
The size of an ion-col can be modified with size-xs/sm/xl/lg and offset option. This will adapte depending on the size of the screen.

You considere that the screen is 12 blocks, and you choose how many blocks you ion-col will take.

More infos : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid and https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/col

```
<ion-content >
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size-sm="6">
    <ion-item>Some stuff</ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size-sm="6">
    <ion-item>Some other stuff</ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-card size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
      <ion-card-title>Stuff again</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>



</ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```